# Create custom driver/executor in OpenMDAO 1.x

Tags: openmdao

I am using OpenMDAO to carry out a simulation of a CNC turning process and want to implement my own 'executor(s)' for my `Component`s - much like the [car example](http://openmdao.org/releases/0.10.0/docs/tutorials/complex/overview.html#simulating-the-acceleration-test-0-60) in the older versions of OpenMDAO, where [SimAcceleration driver](http://openmdao.org/releases/0.10.0/docs/tutorials/complex/drivers.html) is used to implement the way the Components will be executed.

However, I don't know how we can implement such an example in OpenMDAO 1.x, where we might want to implement custom logic to drive inputs to and fetch outputs from Components and/or `Group`s. Any pointers will be really helpful.

P.S. - I was thinking of wrapping my Components in a `Problem` and create an instance of it in another Component and put all the execution logic in its `solve_nonlinear` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287786/how-to-use-nested-problems-in-openmdao-1-x)). But I'm not sure if this is the right approach to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've tended to model time integrations differently recently. Instead of using a driver, we now use a component that does the integration and outputs the whole time history as a big array. You can take a look at our code for doing that using [a satellite design problem](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/CADRE/blob/master/src/CADRE/rk4.py). But if you have a big model with lots of components that you want to integrate around, then either a nested problem or a custom driver would do the trick.

If you're going to do some optimization around it, I would try for the nested problem approach. You could make your model, wrap it up as a problem. Then give that problem to some kind of time integrator that you write as its own component. Alternatively, you can wrap the problem in a simple function and hand that function to one of the [scipy integrators](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html)

If you just want to loop over the model in time a driver would work. I would try to start with one of the optimization drivers, and modify it with your own for-loops and such. This would work fine, and might make for an interesting driver.