# What does Error: missing 'probdata' mean in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao, co

I'm just get stared at OpenMDAO and multidisciplinary optimization, I'm going to use OpenMDAO to build a CO(Collaborative Optimization) framwork on the classical [Sellar](http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usr-guide/tutorials/sellar.html) problem.

However, when I ran this code I always get the following error:

> TypeError: _init_sys_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'probdata'

which occurs when running the `problem.setup()`
I've no idear what does this error mean since there's no difference of this line of code to the OpenMDAO standard tut.
Could somebody give me some advices?

Here's the code, some hints from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287786/how-to-use-nested-problems-in-openmdao-1-x)

**Sellar problem formed as CO:**

```
    SystemOpt
    min     x1**2  + z2 + y1 + eye(-y2)
    w.r.t   z1, z2, x1, y1, y2  
    s.t     (z1 - z1_d1)**2 + (x1 - x1_d1)**2 + (z2 - z2_d1)**2 + 0.2 * (y2 - y2_d1) <= epsilon
            (y2 - y2_d2)**2 + (y1 - y1_d2)**2 + (z1 - z1_d2)**2 + (z2 - z2_d2)**2 <= epsilon
            -10 <= z1 <= 10
            0 <= z2 <= 10
            0 <= x1 <= 10


    SobOpt1
        min     (z1 - z1_d1)**2 + (x1 - x1_d1)**2 + (z2 - z2_d1)**2 + 0.2 * (y2 - y2_d1)
        w.r.t   z1_d1, x1_d1, z2_d1, y2_d1
        s.t     z1_d1**2 + x1_d1 + z2_d1 - 0.2 * y2_d1 >= 3.16
                0 <= x1_d1 <=10
                -10 <= z1_d1 <= 10
                0 <= z2_d1 <= 10



    SubOpt2
        min     (y2 - y2_d2)**2 + (y1 - y1_d2)**2 + (z1 - z1_d2)**2 + (z2 - z2_d2)**2
        w.r.t   y2_d2, y1_d2, z1_d2, z2_d2
        s.t     y1_d2 ** 0.5 + z1_d2 + z2_d2 <= 24
                -10 <= z1_d2 <= 10
                0 <= z2_d2 <= 10
```

## ==================================================

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import ExecComp, IndepVarComp, Group
from openmdao.api import Component, ScipyOptimizer

class Discipline1(Component):
    """Component containing Discipline 1."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(Discipline1, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('z1_d1', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('x1_d1', val=0.)
        self.add_param('z2_d1', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('y2_d1', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('z1', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('x1', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('z2', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('y2', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('obj1', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """
        Evaluates the equation
        y1 = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2
        """

        z1_d1 = params['z']
        z2_d1 = params['z2_d1']
        x1_d1 = params['x1_d1']
        y2_d1 = params['y2_d1']
        z1 = params['z1']
        x1 = params['x2']
        z2 = params['z2']
        y2 = params['y2']

        unknowns['obj1'] = (z1 - z1_d1) ** 2 + (x1 - x1_d1) ** 2 + (z2 - z2_d1) ** 2 + 0.2 * (y2 - y2_d1)


class SubOpt1(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Sobopt of discipline1
        """
        super(SubOpt1, self).__init__()
        self.add_param('S1px', IndepVarComp('x1_d1', 1.0), promotes=['x1_d1'])
        self.add_param('S1pz', IndepVarComp('z1_d1', 5.0), promotes=['z1_d1'])
        self.add_param('S1pz', IndepVarComp('z2_d1', 5.0), promotes=['z2_d1'])
        self.add_param('S1py2', IndepVarComp('y2_d1', 2.0), promotes=['y2_d1'])
        # Add Problem
        from openmdao.api import Problem
        self.problem = prob = Problem()
        group = prob.root = Group()
        # add Component:
        group.add('Discipline', Discipline1,
                  promotes=['x1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x1_d1', 'z1_d1', 'x2_d2', 'y2_d2', 'obj1'])
        # Add Cons
        group.add('con', ExecComp('con = z1_d1**2 + x1_d1 + z2_d1 - 0.2 * y2_d1'),
                  promotes=['con', 'z1_d1', 'x1_d1', 'z2_d1', 'y2_d1'])
        # Add Solver
        prob.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
        prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
        prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1.0e-8

        # Add desvar
        prob.driver.add_desvar('x1_d1', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)
        prob.driver.add_desvar('z1_d1', lower=-10.0, upper=10.0)
        prob.driver.add_desvar('z2_d1', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)
        prob.driver.add_desvar('y2_d1')

        # Add obj and cons
        prob.driver.add_objective('obj1')
        prob.driver.add_constraint('con', lower=3.16)

        prob.setup()

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params=None, unknowns=None, resids=None, metadata=None):
        self.problem.run()
        unknowns['obj1'] = self.problem['obj1']


class Discipline2(Component):
    """Component containing Discipline 1."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(Discipline2, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('z1_d2', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('z2_d2', val=0.)
        self.add_param('y1_d2', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('y2_d2', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('z1', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('y1', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('z2', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('y2', val=1.0)
        # add objs
        self.add_param('obj2', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """
        Evaluates the equation
        y1 = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2
        """

        z1_d2 = params['z1_d2']
        z2_d2 = params['z2_d2']
        y1_d2 = params['y1_d2']
        y2_d2 = params['y2_d2']
        z1 = params['z1']
        y1 = params['y2']
        z2 = params['z2']
        y2 = params['y2']

        unknowns['obj2'] = (y2 - y2_d2) ** 2 + (y1 - y1_d2) ** 2 + (z1 - z1_d2) ** 2 + (z2 - z2_d2) ** 2


class SubOpt2(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Subopt of discipline2
        """
        super(SubOpt2, self).__init__()
        # Add Desvar
        self.add_param('S2pz', IndepVarComp('z1_d2', 5.0), promotes=['z1_d2'])
        self.add_param('S2pz', IndepVarComp('z2_d2', 5.0), promotes=['z2_d2'])
        self.add_param('S2py1', IndepVarComp('y1_d2', 2.0), promotes=['y1_d2'])
        self.add_param('S2py2', IndepVarComp('y2_d2', 5.0), promotes=['y2_d2'])

        # Add problem
        from openmdao.api import Problem
        self.problem = prob = Problem()
        group = prob.root = Group()
        # Add Component:
        group.add('Discipline2', Discipline2,
                  promotes=['obj2', 'y2', 'y2_d2', 'y1', 'y1_d2', 'z1', 'z1_d2', 'z2', 'z2_d2'])
        # Add cons:
        group.add('con2', ExecComp('con = y1_d2 ** 0.5 + z1_d2 + z2_d2'),
                  promotes=['con', 'y1_d2', 'z1_d2', 'z2_d2'])
        # Add solver:
        prob.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
        prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
        prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1.0e-8

        # Add desvar
        prob.driver.add_desvar('y1_d2')
        prob.driver.add_desvar('y2_d2')
        prob.driver.add_desvar('z1_d2', lower=-10, upper=10)
        prob.driver.add_desvar('z2_d2', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)

        # Add ovj and cons
        prob.driver.add_objective('obj2')
        prob.driver.add_constraint('con2', upper=24)

        prob.setup()

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params=None, unknowns=None, resids=None, metadata=None):
        self.problem.run()


class System_Opt(Group):
    """
    Group containing the Sellar MDA. This version uses the disciplines
    with derivatives."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(System_Opt, self).__init__()

        self.add('px', IndepVarComp('x1', 1.0), promotes=['x1'])
        self.add('pz1', IndepVarComp('z1', 5.0), promotes=['z1'])
        self.add('pz2', IndepVarComp('z2', 5.0), promotes=['z2'])
        self.add('py1', IndepVarComp('y1', 2.0), promotes=['y1'])
        self.add('py2', IndepVarComp('y2', 2.0), promotes=['y2'])

        self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj = x1**2  + z2 + y1 + eye(-y2)',
                                     z2=0.0, x1=0.0, y1=0.0, y2=0.0),
                 promotes=['obj', 'z2', 'x1', 'y1', 'y2'])

        self.add('SubOpt1', SubOpt1, promotes=['z1_d1', 'x1_d1', 'z2_d1', 'y2_d1', 'x1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2'])
        self.add('SubOpt2', SubOpt2, promotes=['y2_d2', 'y1_d2', 'z1_d2', 'z2_d2', 'y2', 'y1', 'z1', 'z2'])

        self.add('con_cmp1',
                 ExecComp('con1 = (z1 - z1_d1)**2 + (x1 - x1_d1)**2 + (z2 - z2_d1)**2 + 0.2 * (y2 - y2_d1)'),
                 promotes=['con1', 'z1', 'z1_d1', 'x1', 'x1_d1', 'z2', 'z2_d1', 'y2', 'y2_d1'])
        self.add('con_cmp2',
                 ExecComp('con2 = (y2 - y2_d2)**2 + (y1 - y1_d2)**2 + (z1 - z1_d2)**2 + (z2 - z2_d2)**2'),
                 promotes=['con2', 'y2', 'y2_d2', 'y1', 'y1_d2', 'z1', 'z1_d2', 'z2', 'z2_d2'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    epsilon = 1e-5
    from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizer

    # Add problem
    top = Problem()
    top.root = System_Opt()
    # Add solver
    top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
    top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
    top.driver.options['tol'] = 1.0e-8

    # Add desvar
    top.driver.add_desvar('x1', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)
    top.driver.add_desvar('z1', lower=-10.0, upper=10.0)
    top.driver.add_desvar('z2', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)
    top.driver.add_desvar('y2')
    top.driver.add_desvar('y1')

    # Add obj and cons
    top.driver.add_objective('obj')
    top.driver.add_constraint('con1', upper=epsilon)
    top.driver.add_constraint('con2', upper=epsilon)

    top.setup()

    # add init params of desvar
    top['x1'] = 1.0
    top['z1'] = 1.0
    top['z2'] = 1.0
    top['y2'] = 1.0
    top['y1'] = 1.0
    top.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is related to the following lines: 

`self.add('SubOpt1', SubOpt1, promotes=['z1_d1', 'x1_d1', 'z2_d1', 'y2_d1', 'x1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2'])
        self.add('SubOpt2', SubOpt2, promotes=['y2_d2', 'y1_d2', 'z1_d2', 'z2_d2', 'y2', 'y1', 'z1', 'z2'])`

Note that here you passed the **class** into the add method, instead of an instance. You also did the same thing in SubOpt1 and SubOpt2

`group.add('Discipline', Discipline1,
                  promotes=['x1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x1_d1', 'z1_d1', 'x2_d2', 'y2_d2', 'obj1'])
        # Add Cons`

Instead, you need to pass instances into them as follows:

`self.add('SubOpt1', SubOpt1(), promotes=['z1_d1', 'x1_d1', 'z2_d1', 'y2_d1', 'x1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2'])
        self.add('SubOpt2', SubOpt2(), promotes=['y2_d2', 'y1_d2', 'z1_d2', 'z2_d2', 'y2', 'y1', 'z1', 'z2'])`

There are a few other minor typos in your script related to variable names, but the class vs instance issue is your main problem